# How would a SIP request would look like when inviting more clients to conversation

Tags: uac, voip, sip, multimedia

I've finished my SIP client and it works, as long as it comes to one on one, or x on x if the participants are defined in the beginning of the call.

I would like to attach a caller or a callee in the middle of the call, I understand the main issue is in the media session joining implementation, but I do need to tell the new participant the details of all the participants involved, how would it be best to implement this?

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like ChrisW says, [RFC 4353](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4353) is your friend here.

Before you actually implement the logic around conferencing, you need several bits and pieces. You need to support the [Join](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3911) header, the [REFER](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3515) method (which builds on the [events package](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3625). You may also need the [Replaces](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3891) header, and support [call transfer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5589).

The [Call Control RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4579) will show you the actual call flows around adding/removing participants etc.

Also, take a look at the [relevant section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5411#section-16) of the Hitchhiker's Guide to SIP.

And, as always, the [sip-implementors](https://lists.cs.columbia.edu/cucslists/listinfo/sip-implementors) list is a good source of help.

Comment: Hey, I've looked at the schemes in this RFC you specified, and I don't understand one thing, I could refer all the clients to contact each other via SIP messages, and I have a media session that allow multi-uni-cast broadcasting, why would I need a "mixer", or a "focus" to manage my transmissions?

Comment: (Warning: I don't know much about SIP conferencing.) Without a focus, each of the N participants would need to make N-1 calls to the other participants, resulting in N*(N-1)/2 calls in total. The focus allows for far fewer calls, and a central conference policy. The mixer serves the same role as the focus, only on the media plane.

Comment: so it is actually a server implementation... right? I just need to know how to ask the server to connect with more then one client?

Comment: I think so: a URI uniquely identifies a conference, so a UAS gets to decide all this fun stuff. But check with RFC 4579.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you tell the new participant the details of all the participants involved; instead, I think that you have participants talking to a media server, which mixes the media from the several call-legs:

- Either, one of the original participants (the one which invites the 3rd party) acts as the media server: this UAC therefore has two separate calls, one to each of the other two parties, and mixes the media.
- Or, the original participants transfer to a separate, dedicated media server: which subsequently has 3 calls (one to each of the three parties), and mixes the media.

---

**Edit:**

Here's an example of the former method: [Three-Way Conference (Third Party Joins)](http://www.tech-invite.com/Ti-sip-service-11.html)

Here are examples of the latter method: [A Framework for Conferencing with the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)](http://www.packetizer.com/rfc/rfc4353/)

Comment: RFC 4353 allows for ad hoc conferences too, where the focus remains with a participant, rather than migrating to a separate server. Look at section 6.2!

Comment: thanks for the info, will get to it as soon as I get the chance.